# Change all dup-references to references to MAX(id)

Tags: sqlite

This is a question about sqlite.

```
customers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)
orders (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cid INTEGER)
```

I want to remove all duplicate entries from `customers` (keeping the MAX(id) entry). But before that, I want to change all references in `orders` to the corresponding MAX(id) value.

This is what I think does the right thing:

```
UPDATE orders
SET cid = (SELECT  MAX(c.id)
           FROM customers c
           JOIN (SELECT  name, id
                 FROM  customers
                 WHERE id = orders.cid) q
           ON c.name = q.name
           GROUP BY c.name);

DELETE FROM customers
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id)
                 FROM customers
                 GROUP BY name);
```

But especially the first query is extremely slow already with some 10,000 customers. Is there a faster way to do this?

Some numbers: We have 120,000 customers of which appx. 30,000 have COUNT(*) > 1 (when GROUP BY name). In addition to that we have 200,000 orders. It takes almost 20 minutes to complete the above queries.

Comment: Are there any indexes?

Comment: I added info to table structures. `id` is a PRIMARY KEY. That's it. No further indices. This is just a toy example. In the real setting, we have much more columns we want to GROUP BY etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might obtain better performance with a temp table of IDs. As I understand it, SQLite is having trouble with this query because at every update and delete, Customers changes. Note that this approach would be best suited in a transaction.

```
BEGIN Transaction;
```

<strike>CREATE Temp Table TempCustomers As SELECT id, MAX(id) as MaxId
           FROM customers
           GROUP BY name;</strike>

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TempCustomers AS 
    SELECT k.id, q.MaxId 
    FROM customers k JOIN 
       (SELECT MAX(d.id) as MaxId, d.name FROM customers d GROUP BY d.name)
    q ON q.name = k.name;

UPDATE orders
    SET cid = (SELECT MaxId
       FROM TempCustomers c
       WHERE id = orders.cid);

DELETE FROM customers
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MaxId
             FROM TempCustomers);

COMMIT;
```

When you disconnect your Temp table will be erased from memory. Or you can use `DROP Temp Table` if you want to keep the connection and not hog up memory.

EDIT: Final approach suggested as it evolved in comments.

First, add an index to orders.cid. Then create the temp table with a primary key, and insert the id swaps into it (instead of creating on the fly). Finally, perform cleanup.

```
BEGIN Transaction;

CREATE TEMP TABLE TempCustomers
   (Id Integer PRIMARY KEY,
    MaxId Integer);

INSERT INTO TempCustomers SELECT k.id, q.MaxId 
    FROM customers k JOIN 
       (SELECT MAX(d.id) as MaxId, d.name FROM customers d GROUP BY d.name)
    q ON q.name = k.name;

UPDATE orders
    SET cid = (SELECT MaxId
       FROM TempCustomers c
       WHERE id = orders.cid);

DELETE FROM customers
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MaxId
             FROM TempCustomers);

DROP TABLE TempCustomers;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: That's great, same thing that takes 20 to 30 minutes with my queries is done with your code in no more than 3 minutes.

Comment: Hm, I don't think your TempCustomers looks as it should look. It does NOT contain as many rows as customers. Maybe we rather want something like this: CREATE TEMP TABLE TempCustomers AS
                SELECT k.id, q.MaxId
                FROM customers k
                JOIN (SELECT MAX(d.id) as MaxId, d.name
                      FROM customers d
                      GROUP BY d.name) q
                ON q.name = k.name

Comment: @thomas Yes, you're correct. That was not a good TempCustomers. I hope that's not why you got the speed boost...

Comment: No, it's still factor 5 faster :) Thanks!

Comment: As an experiment, maybe rework the Temp table to give it an index on the ID column. I think you can Create an empty TempCustomer table with an Id and a MaxId, with Id as a PK, then Insert into it your correlated query. And I'm really curious to know if you'll get another boost :)

Comment: You also might want an index on Orders.Cid.

Comment: Wow, that's actually incredibly fast. Adding an index for orders.cid and making TempCustomers.id a PK brings down the thing from over 20 minutes (i.e. my first try in the original post) to no more than 20 seconds (!).

Comment: @thomas Optimizing SQLite queries was a big part of my job at my previous employer. :)